# CSV translation word doesn't work only in a specific server environment

Tags: magento, csv, translation

I configured my Magento in es_AR and it works, it translates everithing ok. But happends that one word `"Wishlist","Lista de deseos"` works in my machine locally, works also ok in one server but in another it dosnt translate. It continues showing "Wishlist". And all the rest of the traductions are ok. So weird. Any guess? Im working with Magento Enterprise versión 1.12.0.0. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache and refresh - or translate it in the locale files of Magento: app\locale\es_AR\Mage_Customer.csv

Look for Wishlist there and change it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have different  Developer Mode sttings (on/off) via your index.php. Maybe you have some DB-Translations differing in the systems.